# Fonts in Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, fonts

How do I set my Linux eclipse version to have the same font as the default one on the windows version? What is the font and how do I change it?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this is not easy - it seems like a systematic font problem in Linux, not Eclipse. You can try different things:

- http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/smaller-font-sizes-for-eclipse-on-linux/
- http://blog.xam.dk/?p=70
- http://fedorasolved.org/Members/khaytsus/improve-fonts

  - This is discussed in the previous: http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/
- Human theme: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/human_ultracompact?content=81128

I tried a lot of options (on Ubuntu - might worth retagging with your version of Linux, as that changes the procedure/ease of installation of different options a bit), but was not satisfied with the result.

Hope you are of better luck or just like it the way it looks afterwards.